# Android - Recieving all push notifications, not distinguished by TAG

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android, sdk, push-notification

I've setup the MC Sdk, I am recieving notifications as intended. The thing is that if I send a notification only to one specific Tag I am not subscribed to, I get the notification anyway.

While debugging, when I do sdk.getRegistrationManager().getTags() I see that I recieve 3 additional tags apart that the ones I am subscribed to:
"ALL", "Android", "DEBUG". And when I cleanTags(), or try to remove them manually they don't get removed.

Which is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2-3 `Tags` set for an Android device by default: `ALL` and `Android` for non-debug builds and and additional `Tag` of `DEBUG` for debug builds.

Similarly, `ALL`, `iOS` and `DEBUG` will be set for iOS devices.

Are you setting a `Contact Key`?  I ask because `Tags` are aggregated for a contact.  If you have multiple devices, or have previously set a `Tag` for a given `Contact Key` then it will persist for the new device Registration.

Also, ultimately this is an `inclusion-list` issue as the SDK will simply display what is sent to the device.